# Springboot RestControler multiple produces

Tags: spring-boot

I have one method in my RestController that produces 2 types of return

```
@PostMapping(value = {"myUrl"}, produces = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```

So when are everything ok. the method return the multipart_form but when I got some validation error, I need to return that error in a JSON type.

It`s possible to make this? in my requet (with postman) if I insert in Accept header */*, when I got error the return are 406 not acceptable(and not the json), but if I put application/json he return my succes in a Json too :(

It`s possible to return 2 dif produces in one request? how

tks

Comment: what happens if you throw the error from the controller instead of returning in response

Comment: @Saravanan I throwing the error :/